# Identify a 320V DC Brushless IC Power MOSFET(?) Driver

Tags: integrated-circuit

I need some help identifying this IC. It comes from a bladeless fan.

It is presumably a 230V Power MOSFET(?) element connected to the FCM8201 Three-Phase Sine-Wave BLDC Motor Controller.

The thick top traces come from a capacitor connected to the rectified 230V AC.

More photos on the [EEVBlog Forum](http://www.eevblog.com/forum/repair/bladeless-fan-repair-help-needed/).

[image: front view]
[image: back view]

Comment: this is not exactly offtopic here but we specialize more in software. I suspect you may get an answer faster over at [electronics.SE](https://electronics.stackexchange.com/), those guys know a lot more about chips.